# how to redirect values from select options

Tags: php, jquery

i have a radio button option and a select option, the values from drop downs depends on what im selecting in radio buttons, then when i select from drop downs i want it to be redirected to another php page, but its not redirecting properly because my value would be equal to `"test1.php Wireline"`, it has the link plus the class so dropdowns would be filtered...
here are my codes,

```
<tr>
<td align="center">
<label><input type="radio" name="Radio1" id="Radio1" value="Wireless" />
Wireless</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="Radio1" id="Radio1" value="Wireline" />
Wireline</label></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td align="center"><select name="Category" id="Category">
<option value=" Wireline Wireless" selected="selected">--</option>
<option value="test1.php Wireline">test1</option>
<option value="test2.php Wireline">test2</option>
<option value="test3.php Wireless">test3</option>
<option value="test4.php Wireless">test4</option>
</select><input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>
```

here is my jquery,

```
$(function() {

    $("#submit").hide();

    $("#Category").change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).val();
    })

});
```

Comment: why dont u use the class attribute to filter and the value attribute to save the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using split to get the url

```
$("#Category").change(function() {
    var loc = $(this).val().split(" ")[0];
    if(loc)
        window.location.href = loc;
})
```

I added the if so that the first option was null and wouldn't navigate

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use a custom attribute to filter and value as URL :

```
<select name="Category" id="Category">
    <option value="test1.php" data-filter="Wireline" selected="selected">--</option> 
</select>
```

And Your code :

```
$("#Category").change(function() {
    if($(this).val().indexOf('.php') != -1) window.location = $(this).val();
})
```

To acces your filter, you just have to do

```
$('#Category').children(':selected').data('filter');
```

Comment: That's not valid markup, you can't just make up attribute names. If you need to use custom attributes, they should be HTML5's [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Answer (score 0):

You may add an attribute for each option which holds the php name page.

APTT

and then in your script:

```
 $("#Category").change(function() {
 window.location = $('#Category" :selected').attr('myphp');

    })
```

hope this helps